# Python Script to post Authorization Header to specific IP/port

Tags: python, jwt

I need a python script that posts a given Authorization Bearer header to a specific ipand port.

This is what I have so far.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import urllib3
import certifi

http = urllib3.PoolManager(ca_certs=certifi.where())

url = 'http://172.10.10.2:3000'

req = http.request('POST', url, fields={'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjbWQiOiJscyR7SUZTfS1sYSR7SUZTfS90bXAvbmMifQ.EziCTtJn1PpPXvemJllF36w7ADNkhKiktZ5sv9ADR3o'})
print(req.data.decode('utf-8'))
```

I currently get an error when running this stating that the Required authorization token is not found

The bearer code is created manually and then input into the script, if there was a way to import that from the site I create it on that would be helpful.

What I need the output to be in this -

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 172.10.10.2:3000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJjbWQiOiJpcCR7SUZTfWEifQ.RkoZinBcg2_5HRGgv1AtErhscIVBRv2hUcGIF08ZlCM
```

Comment: If you're trying to send an `Authorization` header, you need to set `headers`, not `fields`.

Comment: Hi, I have just swapped out fields for headers and also Headers however I still get erros, 2 different ones in fact for headers - invalid character '&' looking for beginning of value and for Headers - TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Headers'